# Can my spouse work in her home country before entering the US on a J-2?

Tags: usa, visa, j-visa

I will be entering the US on a J-1 Visa on April 1st. My wife will not join me until July 1st. Can she continue to work in her home country up until July 1st?

Comment: She can do what she wants in her home country

Answer (score 20):

She is only in J-2 status when she is in the US. When she is outside the US, she doesn't have a US status and she is not subject to any US regulations about what she can do in J-2 status.